# Pylint and unittest

Tags: pylint

I have a python project that is using pylint and unittest.  Unittest has me using methods called setUp() which pylint doesn't like.  Specifically:

```
C0103: 57,4:<class>.setUp: Invalid name "setUp" for type method (should match [a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,30}$)
```

How can I get pylint to allow setUp as a method name?  I don't see a configuration item called "allowed method names" for example.  I'd rather not use `# pylint: disable=C0103` all over as there are a lot of setUp methods in my code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

change the method-rgx setting in your configuration file (it's in the BASIC section). Something like this should do the trick:

```
method-rgx=(([a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,30})|(setUp)|(tearDown))$
```

Comment: Yeah -- that's good.  My regex is weak, so I was trying to figure that out myself.  Thanks for the help.